# Inserting in a Partially Ordered Tree

Tags: c, arrays, tree

I'm trying to insert an element in a Partially Ordered Tree but when I tried to display the tree which is implemented as an array, it won't show the elements.

Here's the heap structure. I just made it simple for now.

```
typedef struct{
    int Elem[SIZE];
    int last;
}Heap;
```

Here's what I did for my insert.

```
void insertHeap(Heap *HH, int given)
{
    int parent, child, temp;

    if(HH->last < SIZE){
        HH->Elem[HH->last] = given;
        parent = (HH->last - 1) / 2;
        for(child = HH->last ; child >= 0 && HH->Elem[child] <= HH->Elem[parent] ;  child = parent, parent = parent - 1 / 2 ){
            temp = HH->Elem[parent];
            HH->Elem[parent] = HH->Elem[child];
            HH->Elem[child] = temp;
        }
        HH->last++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Care to upload your `Heap` struct definition?

Comment: I don't know what other problems you have, but integer division in C doesn't work like you think it does. `1/2` in integer arithmetic is zero.

Comment: @Michał Szydłowski  Just uploaded the structure.

Comment: `parent - 1 / 2` should be `(parent - 1) / 2`.And you will need a better condition to stop your loop, probably `child > 0`, because item 0 has no parent.

Comment: @M Oehm Thanks, but I don't get your first sentence. I don't have that statement.

Comment: It's in the update clause of the `for` loop. (The loop might be easier to read as a while `loop` with the two update statements pulled into the loop.)

Comment: @M Oehm If you don't mind, wouldn't that make my code longer? I'm actually concern about efficiency and readability.

Comment: The `while` and `for` loops will have the same statements, only arranged in a different way. I doubt that the compiled code for the two variants should be drastically different. And I don't find the long `for` control particularly readable, but that's just personal preference, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code goes into an infinite loop. You should fix two things:

- There should be parentheses around `(parent - 1)` when you calculate the new parent in the update section of the `for` loop control;
- Your condition `parent >= 0` will always be true, because even for `parent == 0`, `(parent - 1) / 2` will yield 0, because `-1 / 2` is zero according to C's integer division rules.

So:

```
void insertHeap(Heap *HH, int given)
{
    int parent, child, temp;

    if(HH->last < SIZE){
        HH->Elem[HH->last] = given;
        parent = (HH->last - 1) / 2;
        for (child = HH->last; 
             child > 0 && HH->Elem[child] <= HH->Elem[parent];
             child = parent, parent = (parent - 1) / 2)
        {
            temp = HH->Elem[parent];
            HH->Elem[parent] = HH->Elem[child];
            HH->Elem[child] = temp;
        }
        HH->last++;
    }
}
```

The `for` loop with three long sections looks a bit clumsy. You can also move the variable declarations closer to where the variables are needed and initialise them immediately. The code below does the same, but is more readable, in my opinion, but it's a matter of personal style, of course.

```
void insertHeap(Heap *HH, int given)
{    
    if(HH->last < SIZE){        
        int parent = (HH->last - 1) / 2;
        int child = HH->last;

        HH->Elem[HH->last] = given;

        while (child > 0 && HH->Elem[child] <= HH->Elem[parent]) {
            int temp = HH->Elem[parent];

            HH->Elem[parent] = HH->Elem[child];
            HH->Elem[child] = temp;

            child = parent;
            parent = (parent - 1) / 2;
        }

        HH->last++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the first conditional statement of my for loop `child > 0`